# Generating spectrum color palettes

Tags: java, colors

Is there an easy way to convert between color models in Java (RGB, HSV and Lab).

Assuming RGB color model:

- How do I calculate black body spectrum color palette? I want to use it for a heatmap chart.
- How about single-wavelength spectrum?

**Edit:** I found that the [ColorSpace](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html) class can be used for conversions between RGB/CIE and many other color models.

Comment: Thanks, all the answers are good. I selected the one that reflects the approach that I actually used (gradient black-red-yellow-white)

Comment: some related QA's of mine worth looking:  [RGB values of visible spectrum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) and [Star B-V color index to apparent RGB color](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22630970/2521214)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build such a palette using the HSV color-model. That's easy once you have the HSV to RGB code in place and play around with the numbers for some minutes.

However, I think it's not worth it to add the code to your project just to generate a little palette.

It's much easier and less work to extract the palettes you need from a file and add them as a static array.

Photoshop let's you edit palettes and comes with a very nice black body palette as a preset.

You can simply save these as a .act file. The file itself is just a simple 256 color á 3 byte file (order is read, green, blue. 8 bits per channel).

Answer (score 25):

Java has built-in RGB to HSB conversion. Whenever I need a quick pallet of colors in Java I just do this:

```
public Color[] generateColors(int n)
{
    Color[] cols = new Color[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cols[i] = Color.getHSBColor((float) i / (float) n, 0.85f, 1.0f);
    }
    return cols;
}
```

It is a quick and dirty hack (I would tweak the 'magic' numbers for your app), but for my simple uses it generates a nice bright pleasant pallet.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but you can't really generate a true black-body spectrum from an RGB output device. Limited color gamut would be an issue, if nothing else. If all you want is something that visually resembles a black-body spectrum, that's probably a lot easier.

As an approximation, ramp from (R,G,B) (0,0,0) to (255,0,0), then to (255,255,0), then to (255,255,255). That'd give you the dull-red to orange, to yellow, to white transition.

If you want something more scientific, the Wikipedia article on [black body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) has some plots of color vs temperature. Once you figure out the CIE coordinates, you can translate those to RGB in your favorite color space.

Edit: found some other online references:
[What color is the Sun?](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/colour/Tspectrum.html)
[What color is a blackbody?](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/)

Comment: Sorry, I meant a projection of BBS in the monitor's color space (the kind of gradient that is used for heatmaps). The links are interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate this color spectrum https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktLmt.jpg

using the following code:

```
public void render(Screen screen) {
    int green = 255;
    int red = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 255 * 2; i++) {
        int rate = i / 255;

        screen.fillRect((x + (i * width)/6), y, width, height, new Color(red, green, 0));

        red += 1 - rate;
        green -= rate;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a nice way to make a HSL color square in AS3.

```
/**
 * Generate a BitmapData HSL color square (n x n) of hue
 * At a low n dimension you get cool blocky color palettes (e.g. try n=10)
 */
function generateColorSquare(n:uint, hue:uint):BitmapData
            {
                var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(n, n, false, 0xFFFFFF);
                for (var i:uint=n*n; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    bd.setPixel(i % n, Math.floor(i / n),  HSBColor.convertHSBtoRGB(hue, i / (n*n), (1/n) * (i % n) ));
                }
                return bd;
            }
```