# How to find eye color in opencv

Tags: opencv, tracking

I am running a facetracker which detects eye's as well.
Now i end up with an image of the eye in which i want to find out what eye color that person has. The image is not very high resolution but it contains the whole eye.

What would be the best approach to find out the eye color?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050250/fast-way-of-getting-the-dominant-color-of-an-image

Comment: Do you have enough resolution to see the pupil? Would you be able to detect/segment the iris e.g. with a circle detector? As an important detail for your question, you can specify which width/diameter in pixel is your iris in the image. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_%28anatomy%29

Comment: that might be possible in most situations i think. So i would first run a sobel / edge detection? and which cv function can detect circles?

Comment: ok got it somehow working with HoughCircles function. The iris is found pretty robust. The pupil is too small to detect. But i can work from the iris and sample colors from there.